# Output gives 0 value but calculation was declared

Tags: c#

I have declared the the calculation for the Age Calculation but the output is 0 for the age in the class. The following is a code for the class and main method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class HeartRateData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int CurrentYear { get; set; }
    public int BirthYear { get; set; }

    public int personAge;

    public int AgeCalc
    {
        set
        {
            personAge = CurrentYear - BirthYear;
        }
        get
        {   
            return personAge;
        }
    }
}
```

Main Method

```
using System;

class HeartRate
{
    static void Main()
    {
        HeartRateData person1 = new HeartRateData();
        Console.Write("First Name: ");
        string fName = Console.ReadLine();
        person1.FirstName = fName;
        Console.Write("Last Name: ");
        string lName = Console.ReadLine();
        person1.LastName = lName;
        Console.Write("Key in your birth year: ");
        int bYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        person1.BirthYear = bYear;
        Console.Write("Key in the Current Year: ");
        int cYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        person1.CurrentYear = cYear;
        Console.WriteLine($"Your Age is {person1.AgeCalc}");
    }
}
```

The only thing that i did was removing the set method in the AgeCalc class and edited the return class to the following:

```
        get
        {   
            int personAge = CurrentYear - BirthYear;
            return personAge;
        }
```

and even

```
        get
        {   
            return CurrentYear - BirthYear;
        }
```

Both worked but i cant seem to understand why my previous code did not. Mind sharing your thoughts on this?

Comment: Where in your code do you think `set` of `AgeCalc` is called? If you start your debugger, you will find out it's "never".

Comment: When did you expect the setter of `AgeCalc` to run? Also: a setter which does not use `value` to do something, is really suspicious.

Comment: You don't need a setter in AgeCalc, because it's... calculated ;)

Comment: Side note: Making `AgeCalc` a property here is very confusing. You should almost certainly change it to be a method, and much of your confusion will go away.

Comment: And as a side note - you should never trust user input. What if the user enters some string that can't be parsed as an integer when you ask for year of birth, or current year?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the prompt response everyone! I did try calling the set method as person1.AgeCalc(); but there was an error: Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

As you don't give a default value to the `personAge` variable, it gets set to 0.

```cs
public int personAge;

// same as 
public int personAge = 0;
```

You only update this field in the `AgeCalc` property's setter function, which is called only after you set a value to the property, such as

```cs
person1.AgeCalc = 42
```

Therfore, is you access `AgeCalc` **before** setting it a value, the getter will return 0 : the default value of `personAge`

## Why did your change make it work ?

By changing the `AgeCalc` property's getter function to

```cs
get
{   
   return CurrentYear - BirthYear;
}
```

You're basically recalculating what the setter does, thus it will return the correct value even if you have not called the setter.